# NSOSStatusError

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am try to play a number of audios in my app and it is working fine upto 3 times.
But when i am trying to play in 4th time it shows the error .                              Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-43 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)" .the code is

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Sun.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

 NSError *error;
 AudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

 AudioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

 AudioPlayer.volume=1.0;

 if (AudioPlayer == nil)
 {
    NSLog([error description]);    
 }
 else
    [AudioPlayer play];
```

Anybody  figure it out before..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you aren't releasing the AudioPlayer object. So the fact you can play three times is probably related to the number of open files you can have in the AVAudioPlayer object.

look into the delegate methods for AVAudioPlayer: specifically

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
- (void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error
```

you'll want to do something like

(in your main code)

```
AudioPlayer.delegate = self;
```

then add function like

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
     [player release];
}
```

I'm sure you can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `macerror` command line utility to find out what an OSStatus code is:

```
macerror -43
```

Output:

```
Mac OS error -43 (fnfErr): File not found
```

i.e. the file you tried to use doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm trying to stream audio from a remote server and is getting error code -43. The url works when entered in the browser. I suspect AVAudioPlayer cannot play streamed audio.

Comment: It can and it can't. Depends on the streaming protocol and the audio format.